# How AspNet Identity generates user claims

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, claims, identityserver4

I have a scenario with a Single Page Application implemented with Typescript that uses oidc-client to get id_token and access_token from a AspNet Core application that uses IdentityServer4.

At the identity server I am also using Identity with EntityFramework, so that I can retrieve User and their profile to generate claims, etc.

I am facing a strange situation where I am for example updating the `FirstName` for a user, it gets updated properly in database but when generating the user level claims (`given_name`, `family_name`, `name` and `email`) the given_name is not updated with the new name therefore the id_token issued does not contain the updated information in the claims.

I have something like this:

```
public class AspNetIdentityProfileService : IProfileService
{
  private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
  private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

  public AspNetIdentityProfileService(UserManager<User> userManager, IUserRepository userRepository)
  {
     _userManager = userManager;
     _userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  // some code where I generate a List<Claim> calling below method

  private async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetUserLevelClaimsAsync(User user)
  {
     //user contains the updated info because it comes from DB.
     List<Claim> userClaims = new List<Claim>();
     var standardClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user); //has old values
     userClaims.AddRange(standardClaims);
     userClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()));
     return userClaims;
  }
}
```

Why is the `await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);` ignoring the updated information for the user? **Where is getting the old information from?**
I have restarted the application, deleting browser cookies in case it was stored at the cookie that the identity server issues for single-sign on purposes.. but I still don't know where the old information is cached.

**UPDATE 1**:
This is the User model.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    //Extend properties
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid? PrimaryBusinessId { get; set; }
    public Business PrimaryBusiness { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(" ", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public DateTime? LastLoggedInOn { get; set; }

    public UserRole Role { get; set; }

    public List<UserBusiness> UserBusinesses { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:
There is an obvious workaround, which is to manually add the claims from the User properties instead relying on the Identity's UserManager. But the question remains, why userManager doesn't retrieve the updated values in DB? and where is it finding the retrieved old values?

```
    private IEnumerable<Claim> GetUserLevelClaims(User user)
    {
        List<Claim> userClaims = new List<Claim>();
        //var standardClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user); //does not retrieve updated fields
        userClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName));
        userClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.LastName));
        userClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        userClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
        userClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()));
        return userClaims;
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your application user data model.

Comment: @Lutando pasted user model on Update 1
FirstName and LastName don't seem to be part of IdentityUser so I added my own properties. Do you think Identity is unable to access the value of these properties? The claims issued for the user have the old name and last name, not sure where these values would be stored at.

Comment: Also added Update 2 with workaround

Comment: I assumed that you didnt actually store those as claims in the database which is why I asked for the user data model. Also that workaround is perfectly fine and a common practice. You are not constrained to only issue the claims that are stored as claims. The tokens you issue do not care how you store or arrange them on your persistence layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `IProfileService` where to get the claims from.

Basically `userManager` from `AspNetCore.Identity` will only get the associated claims for that user. That is, [IdentityUser.Claims](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs#L159). The "old values" still exist in the `AspNetUserClaims` table. If you update the associated entity for that user for whatever claim in the table, then `IProfileService` will issue those updated claims since you are relying on `userManager` to fetch your claims.

Basically to find out what claims belong to a user you can see that there is the 'root table' called `AspNetUsers`. This table has an associated claims called table called `AspNetUserClaims`. This table just maps the users and their 1-M claims. In short, editing a claims value in that table is what you need to do.

Feel free to add more claims to the  in the `IProfileService` in `GetProfileDataAsync`. It is quite common to further add claims based on the table entity itself. as you have demonstrated in your update #2

Answer (score 1):

@Lutando pointed me in the right direction with his comments.

To answer my own question, the user manager is grabbing the claims not from the User table, but from another Identity table called UserClaims.
I didn't know this table was being used but now it makes sense.

As Lutando also suggests, the workaround is perfectly valid and I don't need to rely on the Identity's user manager to generate claims. I don't even need to use this UserClaims table because I have the name and last name as part of my User table as shown in Update 1.